# How to expand a collapsed force-directed tree (AMCharts 4) with a function (API)?

Tags: amcharts, expand

I took your force-directed tree example, and I modified the script to make it collapsed when initialized:
networkseries.maxLevels = 1;
So, when I run only one bubble (“Core”) appears in the middle of the screen.
Now, I wish to expand the whole chart by calling a function (API style), just as a click on the bubble would do.

I tried everything: isActive=true, Visible=true, hidden=false, collapsed, show()…. The chart still shows one bubble and doesn’t expand.

Could you please help me, and tell me what I should put in my Expand function (end of following code) to expand the chart (all levels)?

INDEX.JS :

```
am4core.useTheme(am4themes_animated);
var chart = am4core.create("chartdiv",      am4plugins_forceDirected.ForceDirectedTree);
var networkSeries = chart.series.push(new am4plugins_forceDirected.ForceDirectedSeries())

chart.data = [
{name: "Core", children: [{
    name: "First", children: [
            { name: "A1", value: 100 },
            { name: "A2", value: 60 }
            ]},{
    name: "Second", children: [
            { name: "B1", value: 135 },
            { name: "B2", value: 98 }
            ]}
    }
]}
];

networkSeries.dataFields.value = "value";
networkSeries.dataFields.name = "name";
networkSeries.dataFields.children = "children";
networkSeries.nodes.template.tooltipText = "{name}:{value}";
networkSeries.nodes.template.fillOpacity = 1;
networkSeries.nodes.template.label.text = "{name}"
networkSeries.fontSize = 10;

networkSeries.maxLevels = 1;

function expand(){
//    ????
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
networkSeries.maxLevels = 2;
```

or

```
networkSeries.maxLevels = 3;
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's too late and you found the solution, but as a workarroud you can do the following:

```
 networkSeries.nodes.each ((node) => {node.isActive = true;})
```

With this you will activate all the nodes one by one, try the solution given by Iñigo but nothing that only seems to work at the beginning of execution.

I hope this solves your problem ^^